# How to assign a keyword to multiple images open in Preview on Mac OS

Tags: macos, preview

I'm adding keyword metadata to a set of images in Preview.app, MacOS 10.6.6

I can select multiple images and create a keyword using the Keywords window.

But when I save, all but one image is deselected and the keyword info is only applied to that image.

I would prefer *not* to use iPhoto, so I don't have to

- add images to it's database
- create an album or event

Is there a way to do this in Preview or some similarly lightweight way to add keywords to a set of images at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview is not AppleScriptable, and there's no Automator action to do this.

---

If you have Aperture, there's an [Automator action](http://macphotographytips.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/using-automator-to-import-photos-into-aperture/) to apply keywords to images.

---

[MacMetaMod](http://xray.bmc.uu.se/markh/photos/macmetamod.html) is a third party droplet application that can apply keywords to selected files.

[image]

---

MacMetaMod uses *ExifTool* internally, which can probably be wrapped in a Mac OS X Service. It can be used from Terminal directly though:

```
exiftool −keywords+=newkeyword test.jpg
```